# SCCM 2007 Server Installation error: "Failed to download prerequisite components (0x80072EE2)"

Tags: sccm-2007

During the installation process on a test Windows 2008 server, which is on a internal IP address, SCCM 2007 wants to download updated versions of some components. This can result in an error message that reads `Failed to download prerequisite component`.

This results in a message in the log `C:\ConfigMgrSetup.log` that reads:

> <05-22-2012 08:36:05> External files directory is C:\sccmdownload
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:05> Checking for component updates...
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:05> Downloading component manifest...
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:05> Downloading http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=141733 as ConfigMgr.manifest.cab
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:07> checking if there's an explicit proxy server.
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:28> WinHttpSendRequest failed 80072ee2
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:28> Download() failed with 0x80072EE2
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:28> Failed to download manifest (0x80072EE2)
>   <05-22-2012 08:36:43> Failed to download prerequisite components (0x80072EE2)

There is already a winhttp proxy set through `netsh`, but that doesn't seem to help. Many posts on technet and other search results indicate that running the downloader separately from the installer can help

> C:\Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager Server 2007 R3 SP2\SCCM 2007 w SP2\SMSSETUP\BIN\I386>SETUP.EXE /download c:\sccmdownload

But for me, this results in the exact same error message in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user who is running the SCCM 2007 server installation process needs to set a proxy in IE -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings.

The installation process does not respect the system wide proxy set in the winhttp context of `netsh`. The line in the error log that reads `checking if there's an explicit proxy server` points in this direction.